# Sharepoint Modern Search v4 KQL

Tags: typescript, search, sharepoint, spfx, spfx-extension

Apologies if this is quite broad

I am trying to create a solution using modern search v4 which using search box to populate results which once one is selected create a query which is then picked up by search results.

Currently I populate the url with a search string to use within the query template in search results to match a "refinablestring" eg. Ref=456, and bring back results, this works with the query template in search results for one field but I'm unsure how to

Use "or" within the query template so two refs to bring back more results

And also to be able to use a wild card so "c324#323" so that I can lookup multiple Ids matching one "refinable string"

I have been suggested to use KQL but I'm unsure how I would then use this to populate the search results

Hopefully this makes sense, is anyone able to assist, happy to supply more info!

Comment: i didnt quite undestand the question but have you tried searching through the docs? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference